# How to order data by duplicates in R?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a dataset I am trying to order by the duplicate IDs in 1 column (rssnp1 column), but I can only find duplicate functions to remove duplicates online.

My data looks like this:

```
Chr  Start   End     rssnp1        Type    gene
1   1244733 1244734 rs2286773   LD_SNP  ACE
1   1257536 1257436 rs301159    LD_SNP  CPEB4
1   1252336 1252336 rs2286773   Sentinel    CPEB4
1   1252343 1252343 rs301159    LD_SNP  CPEB4
1   1254841 1254841 rs301159    LD_SNP  CPEB4
1   1256703 1267404 rs301159    LD_SNP  CPEB4
1   1269246 1269246 rs301159    LD_SNP  CPEB4
1   1370168 1370168 rs301159    LD_SNP  GLUPA1
1   1371824 1371824 rs301159    LD_SNP  GLUPA1
1   1372591 1372591 rs301159    LD_SNP  GLUPA1
```

My output aims to be:

```
Chr  Start   End     rssnp1        Type    gene
1   1244733 1244734 rs2286773   LD_SNP  ACE
1   1252336 1252336 rs2286773   Sentinel    CPEB4
1   1257536 1257436 rs301159    LD_SNP  CPEB4
1   1252343 1252343 rs301159    LD_SNP  CPEB4
1   1254841 1254841 rs301159    LD_SNP  CPEB4
1   1256703 1267404 rs301159    LD_SNP  CPEB4
1   1269246 1269246 rs301159    LD_SNP  CPEB4
1   1370168 1370168 rs301159    LD_SNP  GLUPA1
1   1371824 1371824 rs301159    LD_SNP  GLUPA1
1   1372591 1372591 rs301159    LD_SNP  GLUPA1
```

To reproduce the data, use:

```
structure(list(Chr = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Start = c(1244733, 
1257536, 1252336, 1252343, 1254841, 1256703, 1269246, 1370168, 
1371824, 1372591), End = c(1244734, 1257436, 1252336, 1252343, 
1254841, 1267404, 1269246, 1370168, 1371824, 1372591), rssnp1 = c("rs2286773", 
"rs301159", "rs2286773", "rs301159", "rs301159", "rs301159", 
"rs301159", "rs301159", "rs301159", "rs301159"), Type = c("LD_SNP", 
"LD_SNP", "Sentinel", "LD_SNP", "LD_SNP", "LD_SNP", "LD_SNP", 
"LD_SNP", "LD_SNP", "LD_SNP"), gene = c("ACE", "CPEB4", "CPEB4", 
"CPEB4", "CPEB4", "CPEB4", "CPEB4", "GLUPA1", "GLUPA1", "GLUPA1"
)), .Names = c("Chr", "Start", "End", "rssnp1", "Type", "gene"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I have looked into trying:

```
target_order <- c("a", "b", "c")
df[order(match(df$rssnp1)), target_order]
```

Doing this with every unique value in target_order instead of the
c("a", "b", "c") - so I've got something like c("rs2286773", "rs301159"...) which goes on for the hundreds of IDs I have.
but this gives an error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, order(match(df$rssnp1)), target_order) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Is there any other way I can do this?

Edit:
target_order needed to be in a different part of the code:
`df[order(match(df$rssnp1, target_order)), ]`

However, this is still a tedious way for me to get this is work - are there any more efficient ways of sorting by duplicates?

Comment: There is no column that matches the `target_order`

Comment: I have an idea, but can you post your data in a reproducible format.  Use `dput(head(YOURDATA))` and post the results.

Comment: Perhaps `hutils::duplicated_rows(data.table::as.data.table(df), by = "rssnp1")`

Comment: So essentially your question is less about "duplicates" but rather about how to sort data based on a given variable, right? `dplyr::arrange(df, rssnp1)`

Comment: Or with base R: `with(df, df[order(rssnp1),])`

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding of your description, you want the result to follow certain sequence given by *target_order* calculated somewhere else. This should be able to be done by a merge operation.

Assuming you have the following order.

```
target_order<-c("rs301159", "rs2286773") 

dt <- structure(list(Chr = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Start = c(1244733, 
    1257536, 1252336, 1252343, 1254841, 1256703, 1269246, 1370168, 
    1371824, 1372591), End = c(1244734, 1257436, 1252336, 1252343, 
    1254841, 1267404, 1269246, 1370168, 1371824, 1372591), rssnp1 = c("rs2286773", 
    "rs301159", "rs2286773", "rs301159", "rs301159", "rs301159", 
    "rs301159", "rs301159", "rs301159", "rs301159"), Type = c("LD_SNP", 
    "LD_SNP", "Sentinel", "LD_SNP", "LD_SNP", "LD_SNP", "LD_SNP", 
    "LD_SNP", "LD_SNP", "LD_SNP"), gene = c("ACE", "CPEB4", "CPEB4", 
    "CPEB4", "CPEB4", "CPEB4", "CPEB4", "GLUPA1", "GLUPA1", "GLUPA1"
    )), .Names = c("Chr", "Start", "End", "rssnp1", "Type", "gene"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ))
```

The following code should be able to produce what you want.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dt)

# Setting sort=FALSE to persist the order in target_order
merge(as.data.table(target_order), dt, by.y="rssnp1", by.x="target_order", sort=FALSE)

 #     target_order Chr   Start     End     Type   gene
 #  1:     rs301159   1 1257536 1257436   LD_SNP  CPEB4
 #  2:     rs301159   1 1252343 1252343   LD_SNP  CPEB4
 #  3:     rs301159   1 1254841 1254841   LD_SNP  CPEB4
 #  4:     rs301159   1 1256703 1267404   LD_SNP  CPEB4
 #  5:     rs301159   1 1269246 1269246   LD_SNP  CPEB4
 #  6:     rs301159   1 1370168 1370168   LD_SNP GLUPA1
 #  7:     rs301159   1 1371824 1371824   LD_SNP GLUPA1
 #  8:     rs301159   1 1372591 1372591   LD_SNP GLUPA1
 #  9:    rs2286773   1 1244733 1244734   LD_SNP    ACE
 # 10:    rs2286773   1 1252336 1252336 Sentinel  CPEB4
```